# SQL Developer 4.0.2 connection error 17002 on mac OS X

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

When I try to create a connection using SQL Developer 4.0.2 on MAC OS I got the following error message : 
The Network Adapter could not establish the connection’ (ORA-17002) error.

Comment: Some information about your connection settings might be helpful. Are the host and port valid, is the host resolvable, is there actually a listener running there...

Comment: I'm just new to Oracle and this is first step installing SQL Developer and creating connection as I'm following cbtnuggets tutorial so I don't know what is if there a listener running.

Comment: Do you already have a database to connect to? SQL Developer is a client, not a server.

Answer (score 0):

ORA-17002 is a generic error code shown when the client cannot connect to the database. The actual fix can be found only if we have additional info.

You can start by troubleshooting the following.
1. Check if the database server can be pinged.
2. check if the port is accessible by running telnet.
3. check if there are any firewall rules blocking access to database.

Answer (score 0):

run the below command in mac cli:

```
sudo scutil --set HostName localhost
```

[image]